# How to make multiple pivotitem invisible in Excel Vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a Pivot table in sheet"EX". In pivot "Report Filter" field i have "Country Code" which contain 200 countries. I want to remove (Making invisible) more than 1 countries from that filter using InputBox. I used the code below and it is not working. It is not coming to "If InStr" line. Help me

```
Sub Removecountries()

Dim str1 As Variant
Dim Data As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Ex")
str1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the Country - comma separated")

If str1 = False Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter one Country", , "Filter Country"
Exit Sub

Else

If InStr(1, str1, ",") > 0 Then
Data = Split(str1, ",")
With ws.PivotTables("RemoveTable").PivotFields("Country Code").PivotItems(Data(0)).Visible = False
End With
End If

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is an example user input for the inputbox? I am confused as to why there will be comma separation.

Comment: @QHarr Yes. I will enter country code like FR,GB,DE in input box with comma separated.

Comment: What *is* happening with the code you have?

Comment: Do you not then need a loop to loop over the array from the split?

Comment: @Rory It is not excecuting the `If InStr` part.

Comment: I tried with loop. It is also not working. `Dim arr() As String
Dim size As Long
    size = 1

        Do
        str1 = Application.InputBox("Select one country")
        ReDim Preserve arr(size)
        arr(size) = str1
        size = size + 1
        Loop While (str1 <> vbNullString) And (str1 <> False)`

Comment: Are you seeing a message? If not, then it must be executing the `Instr` part.

Comment: @Rory Yes i am seeing message. then the program end suddenly.

Comment: You could at least try to help us to help you. Is it your message box, or an error message? If the latter, what does it say?

Comment: The input box is working and i am entering country code like FR,GB,..etc. then the program end suddenly. No error is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested the following and it seems to work, the issue seems to be when you only enter one item in the inputbox: (Before you try make sure you edit the "ws.PivotTable" as I changed the name when testing it)

```
Sub Removecountries()

Dim str1 As Variant
Dim Data As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Ex")
str1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the Country - comma separated")

If str1 = False Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter one Country", , "Filter Country"
Exit Sub

Else
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CountryCode").ClearAllFilters
If InStr(1, str1, ",") > 0 Then
Data = Split(str1, ",")
For i = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CountryCode").PivotItems(Data(i)).Visible = False
Next i
Else
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CountryCode").PivotItems(str1).Visible = False
End If

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for the code. Its working almost. But when i am runing the program for the second time the previously applied filter is not going. I need to reset then get the inputbox. How to do that

Comment: Updated the code to reflect your comments, this should do as you expect now, added the line above the If InStr, that will clear the filter before applying it again...

Comment: Thank you very much @xabier